# Powerpoint 2007 downgrade

Tags: windows-xp

I recently downgraded a few machines from Office 2007 to Office 2003. All of the machines are doing great except one. One has an update for Powerpoint 2007 that is stuck trying to install constantly.  The update is KB 957789 and the error code is 0x80070643

Comment: Just curious -- why did you downgrade from Office 07 to Office 03?

Comment: Someone request Office 2007 and I didn't have any spare license. The user I downgraded doesn't use Office that much, so it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth trying out the microsoft install cleanup utility to remove any remnance of office 2007, then maybe it'll stop trying to install the update.

Get the util here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301

Comment: Thanks, there was still Office 2007 Interop Assemblies installed. Once I uninstalled this and rebooted it went away. Thanks. Now if I can just get all these .net framework 3.5 sp1 updates to install without errors...

Comment: cool, glad it helped.
This may be of some use to you if you get stuck, read about this earlier on a forum but appears to be a similar cleanup tool for .net
http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/05/30/611355.aspx